# What are the scopes for use with the new Instance ID API (released at Google I/O 15)

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-cloud-platform

Google released a new Instance ID service and API at I/O 15:
https://developers.google.com/instance-id/

The examples and docs show how to use it with GCM, so they provide the scope to use for getting a security token for use with GCM, but there are other services listed and the API can be used independently of GCM.

In my case, I want to get a token I can use for authenticating my Android app, and one for use with the base Instance ID server API:
https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server

I'm actually not completely clear how app authentication is supposed to work - perhaps it is just getting a good response from the above server API - so probably I just need one token, but still need to know the scope for it.

Answer (score 0):

As described at https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/android-implementation you can use any URL safe string < 1000 chars. What scope is needed depends on what service you are using the instance ID with. If you are just using the instance ID server API it does not matter what scope you use.